# c# Fire Async from Loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

I want to fire an array of async tasks. and each task will return some value when they are done, and I want to use those returned value to do some other things. here is my code

```
async task Start()
{

    List<Task<Tuple<string, int>>> AsyncTasks = new List<Task<Tuple<string, int>>>();

    foreach (string name in NameArray)
    {
        //fire all the async task in this loop
        AsyncTasks.Add(DoAsyncTask(name));
    }

    //Method 1 I tried
    Task<Tuple<string, int>[]> Tasks = Task.WhenAll(VirtualOutPortTasks);

    foreach (var tupleStringInt in Tasks.Result)
    {
        //handle result either async or nonasync here
        //each async task can be handled individually, I dont need to wait for all of them.
        HandleResult(tupleStringInt);
    }

    // Method 2 I tried
     foreach (var tupleStringInt in await Tasks)
    {
        //handle result either async or nonasync here
        //each async task can be handled individually, I dont need to wait for all of them.
        HandleResult(tupleStringInt);
    }
}



async Task<Tuple<string,int>> DoAsyncTask(string name)
    {
        // the someOtherAsyncTask runs an Async task in an DLL that I cant see, 
        // it returns an Task<int>
        int resultInt = await SomeOtherAsyncTask(name);
        return Tuple.Create(name, resultInt );
    }
```

I have 6 value in the NameArray. Each operations takes about 5 second. Right now this code will freeze for 30 second, while it works. So must be doing something right.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? It sounds as though you perhaps got option #1 working, but you are unsure of something about it.

Comment: Which code "freezes"? I would expect `Start` to wait for the results of all tasks so it seems not strange that it "freezes" .. does this also freeze the Unity main thread?

Comment: Did you try to make `async void Start`?

Comment: `Task.Result` is a blocking property. To avoid freezing you must `await` the task.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, these are just some examples.

The premise is you want to start a bunch of *tasks*, and *pipe* them to a method called handle (async or not) having them working asynchronously and not waiting for everything else to finish.

<sub>***Note*** both solution wait for completion, you can choose to do this or not</sub>

```
private static async Task<string> DoAsyncTask(string name)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Do {name}");
   // simulate a delay
   await Task.Delay(5000);
   return name;
}

private static async Task HandleAsync(Task<string> task)
{
   var name = await task;
   Console.WriteLine($"Done {name}");
}

public static async Task Main()
{
   // List of names
   var nameArray = new[] { "task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4", "task 5", "task 6", "task 7", };

   Console.WriteLine("Started " + DateTime.Now);

   // pump the names in to do async, then the resulting tasks in toHandleAsync
   var taskList = nameArray.Select(DoAsyncTask)
                           .Select(HandleAsync);

   // wait for all tasks 
   await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

   Console.WriteLine("Finished " + DateTime.Now);
   Console.ReadKey();

}
```

**Output**

```
Started 1/10/2019 12:08:03 PM
Do task 1
Do task 2
Do task 3
Do task 4
Do task 5
Do task 6
Do task 7
Done task 5
Done task 7
Done task 6
Done task 4
Done task 2
Done task 1
Done task 3
Finished 1/10/2019 12:08:08 PM
```

**Data flow solution** you will need System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow nuget

```
private static async Task<(string, DateTime)> DoAsyncTask(string name)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Do {name}");
   // simulate a delay
   await Task.Delay(5000);

   return (name, DateTime.Now);
}

private static void Handle((string, DateTime) someTuple)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Name {someTuple.Item1}, value {someTuple.Item2}");
}

public static async Task Main()
{
   // List of names
   var nameArray = new[] { "task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4", "task 5", "task 6", "task 7", };

   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
                 {
                    EnsureOrdered = false,
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                 };
   var transform = new TransformBlock<string, (string, DateTime)>(DoAsyncTask, options);
   var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<(string, DateTime)>(Handle, options);

   transform.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions(){PropagateCompletion = true});

   Console.WriteLine("Started " + DateTime.Now);

   foreach (var name in nameArray)
   {
      transform.Post(name);
   }

   transform.Complete();

   await actionBlock.Completion;

   Console.WriteLine("Finished " + DateTime.Now);
   Console.ReadKey();

}
```

**Output**

```
Started 1/10/2019 12:21:17 PM
Do task 2
Do task 1
Do task 4
Do task 3
Do task 5
Do task 6
Do task 7
Name task 2, value 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
Name task 5, value 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
Name task 7, value 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
Name task 3, value 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
Name task 6, value 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
Name task 4, value 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
Name task 1, value 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
Finished 1/10/2019 12:21:22 PM
```

Note you could do this with RX as well

Comment: Unity works a bit different however and while here it doesn't matter that the `Main` freezes until all tasks are done the issue for OP might be that `Start` freezes the entire main thread -> the entire application is non-responsive during the task execution.

Comment: Yes Unity Freeze the entire application. but I followed TheGeneral's example, and was able to get it working non freezing. I will post an answer to show what I did.

Answer (score 0):

OP here,
Thanks to @TheGeneral's example code. Here is what worked for me.

```
async Task Start()
{
    //Method 1: fire all async event, then wait for all async task are completed
    //before handling all the results non asyncally

    List<Task<int>> FiredTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++)
    { 
        Debug.Log("async task firing "+i);
        Tasks.Add(DoAsyncTask("someStringValue", i));
    }

    foreach (int item in await Task.WhenAll(FiredTasks))
    {
        Debug.Log("async task ended, returned result: " + item);
        //add code to handle the returned result here.
    }

    //Method 2, fire all async event, then handle each result as they complete without waiting for others
    List<Task<int>> FiredTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Firing async event "+i);
        Tasks.Add(DoAsyncTask("someStringValue", i));
    }

    //If I understnd correctly, this loop basically tells each of the fired async task what to do when they are done.
    foreach (Task<int> task in FiredTasks)
    {
        await HandleAsyncResult(task);
    }
}

async Task<int> DoAsyncTask(string name, int index)
{
    await Task.Delay(6000);
    // or you can do add some randome delay in here so you can see the individual task completing at different time
    await Task.Delay(UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,10) * 1000);
    return index;
}

async Task HandleAsyncResult(Task<int> task)
{
    int taskResult = await task;
    Debug.Log("Done " + taskResult);
}
```

Debug.Log() is Unity's equivalent to Console.WriteLine();

I wont mark this as correct answer, since I am answering to my own question. but maybe it will be of some use to future people.